# Building C++ gRPC with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

Following the instruction [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md), I managed to build gRPC for multiple programming language. While it is relatively easy to do, this has a disadvantage of having too many dependencies, especially when you want to set these dependencies to be "package", i.e the builder need to provide the dependencies in the system/install folder, and not letting gRPC build from its submodules.

I wonder if there's a way where I can build gRPC for C++ only and don't bother with other programming language?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the problem - those instructions do actually build gRPC for C++ only - they don't build other programming language extensions. gRPC C++ itself does have dependencies on other libraries though.

Comment: In my install/bin folder, I would get grpc_cpp_plugin.exe, grpc_csharp_plugin.exe, grpc_node_plugin.exe and so on. I'm not sure if gRPC ONLY build the C++ version though...